# Invite multiple Slack users to a channel

Tags: slack

I know that in Slack I can invite a user to a channel using `/invite @username` command.

How would I go about inviting multiple users at the same time using a keyboard command? Something like `/invite @user1, @user2...`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible only using the keyboard, **unless** you have a paid team with user groups. Then you can invite a group with `/invite @hr` to invite all members of the @hr group.

Answer (score 1):

I found a Chrome extension that will do the trick!

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/slack-invite-all/okakcmghmbmdgbccjfclfkeednhhlpeg

Answer (score 1):

A trick is to just mention everyone, if they are not in the channel the slack bot will ask you what to do, "invite them" will be among the actions.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Savageman [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/100102/19657), Slack doesn't expose this functionality via a command. You can do it using a mouse click though, there is a button on the top right corner of the channel interface, which you can use to invite people.

[image: Add people to Slack button]

If you are open to using an app though, [Channel Tools for Slack](https://www.channeltools.io) provides `/invite_channel` command which can be used to bulk invite all the users in a Slack channel.

To invite all the members of `#design` channel:

`/invite_channel #design`

Unlike group invites in [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/100102/19657), you don't need to have a paid team to use the command above.

Answer (score -1):

Click the cog top right of the channel, select invite team members to join